# Hover over photos in whatsapp web to activate child element to click?

Tags: jquery, dom, whatsapp

My goal is to select all photos in [whatsapp](https://web.whatsapp.com/)
I try to select all photos from whatsapp web with this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('._33mBu > span').forEach(s => s.click())
```

But it seems that you first have to:

1. hover over each photo (class '_23fpc')
2. now a new div class '_33mBu' becomes visible (a child div)
3. then click this class to select the photo

[image]

You can check out your own whatsapp web version by

1. going to [web.whatsapp.com](https://web.whatsapp.com)
2. authenticate
3. open up a chat
4. click on top of the chat
5. click on media

Answer (score 0):

If it has to do something with the `mouseover` (or maybe the `mouseenter`) event, this might be worth a shot:

```js
const mouseoverEvent = new Event('mouseover');
document.querySelectorAll("._23fpc").forEach(s => s.dispatchEvent(mouseoverEvent));
```

If it works, you can go on with the code you provided.

Comment: Thanks, i just updated my post, because I realise it's about clicking a new div when hovering over it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got this in the jQuery category, here's a JQ way of approaching it. The unknown bit is what the mouseover is doing... it might be triggering some kind of async event before it writes to the page. I have put in a little delay after mouseover which you might need to edit

```
$("._23fpc").each(function () {
  $(this).trigger('mouseenter');
  doMO($(this));
})

function doMO($el) {
 setTimeout(() => {
   $el.trigger('click');
 }, 100)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is wonderful, but it's actually a new class appearing to be clicked. I've updated by post above with a screenshot.